# prepareForSegue not passing correct PFFile

Tags: objective-c, ios, parse-platform

When passing a PFFile into new view I am either getting no image or the wrong image.

Here is prepareForSegue method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowWine"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"image"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setFile:file];

    }
}
```

And the rest of my relevant implementation file, I just think that I am not getting to the right row in the right section?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.sections.allKeys.count;
}


- (NSString *)wineTypeForSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.sectionToWineTypeMap objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:section]];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *wineType = [self wineTypeForSection:section];
    NSArray *rowIndecesInSection = [self.sections objectForKey:wineType]; return  rowIndecesInSection.count;
}

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    [self.sections removeAllObjects];
    [self.sectionToWineTypeMap removeAllObjects];

    NSInteger section = 0;
    NSInteger rowIndex = 0;
    for (PFObject *object in self.objects) {
        NSString *wineType = [object objectForKey:@"wineType"];
        NSMutableArray *objectsInSection = [self.sections objectForKey:wineType];
        if (!objectsInSection) {
            objectsInSection = [NSMutableArray array];

            [self.sectionToWineTypeMap setObject:wineType forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:section++]];
        }

        [objectsInSection addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rowIndex++]];
        [self.sections setObject:objectsInSection forKey:wineType];
    }
}

- (PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *wineType = [self wineTypeForSection:indexPath.section];

    NSArray *rowIndecesInSection = [self.sections objectForKey:wineType];

    NSNumber *rowIndex = [rowIndecesInSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return [self.objects objectAtIndex:[rowIndex intValue]];
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

What you should try doing is the following :

1. Create an instance variable (PFFile *aFile)
2. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, call your `objectAtIndexPath:` method, and set `aFile` with the returning value
3. Still in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, call your `performSegueWithIdentifier:` and in `prepareForSegue:`, just set the destination file to your var : `[[segue destinationViewController] setFile: aFile];`.

Try this, and see if it works better. If not, please let me know !